# UUID for Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, uuid, kotlin-multiplatform

I was trying to use this library https://github.com/benasher44/uuid to generate a Universally Unique IDentifier for a paramater named id in my Children data class but i couldn't figure how i can use it

```
@Serializable

data class Children  constructor(
//val parentId : Long,
val id : Long = //Uuid,
val gender : String,
val firstName : String,
val lastName : String,
val birthDate : String,
val grade : String,
var avatar : String?,
)
```

I tried using the expect/actual mechanism to provide platform-specific implementation for generating UUIDs and it did work but i want to use less code. I used the library mentioned above and i couldn't figure out how it works there was no sample or implementation provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `uuid4().toString()` in common layer, and it should just work.

There is no need to have platform-specific implementation as it's already done by the library